# Intellisense for linked css is not loaded when Visual Studio starts

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, autocomplete, intellisense

I have added a large number of css/js/image files to my visual studio project using the "add as link.." option. After linking them the code completion works as expected in visual studio, however if i close the project and open it back up the code completion does not work at all.

I have found that hitting refresh in the solution explorer will get the code completion working again.

Is there some way to fix this without needing to hit refresh every time i open the project up?

EDIT: Here is my visual studio info.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Installed Version: Enterprise

Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-90150-00242-AA417
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools

UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015   00322-90150-00242-AA417
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015   00322-90150-00242-AA417
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015

Visual Basic 2015   00322-90150-00242-AA417
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-90150-00242-AA417
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-90150-00242-AA417
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Add New File   3.5
The fastest and easiest way to add new files to any project - including files that start with a dot

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1   14.1.21111.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v2.8.1   14.0.11123.0
Azure App Service Tools v2.8.1

Browser Reload on Save   1.0.20
A Visual Studio extension for ASP.NET projects that leverages Browser Link to to reload all connected browsers when files are saved in Visual Studio.

Bundler & Minifier   2.2.307
Adds support for bundling and minifying JavaScript, CSS and HTML files in any project.

Common Azure Tools   1.8
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

File Icons   2.1
Adds icons for files that are not recognized by Solution Explorer

File Nesting   2.5.65
Automatically nest files based on file name and enables developers to nest and unnest any file manually

Image Optimizer   3.6.103
Uses industry standard tools to optimize any JPEG, PNG and Gifs - including animated Gifs. Can do both lossy and lossless optimization.

Image Sprites   1.4.47
Boost your website's performance by creating image sprites to reduce the amount of HTTP requests needed.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

Markdown Editor   1.10.186
A full featured Markdown editor with live preview and syntax highlighting. Supports GitHub flavored Markdown.

Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 2)   14.1.21111.0
Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 2)

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

Multiline Search and Replace   1.6
Adds multiline search and replace functionality to Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   3.5.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 ENU   14.0.23928
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 ENU

Open Command Line   2.1.179
Opens a command line at the root of the project. Support for all consoles such as CMD, PowerShell, Bash etc. Provides syntax highlighting, Intellisense and execution of .cmd and .bat files.

Package Installer   2.0.94
Makes it easier, faster and more convenient than ever to install Bower, npm, Yarn, JSPM, TSD, Typings and NuGet packages to any project

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Syntax Highlighting Pack   2.1.89
Adds syntax highlighting and snippet support for a wide variety of programming languages such as Clojure, Go, Jade, Lua, Swift, Ruby and many more...

TypeScript   1.8.36.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

Web Compiler   1.11.326
Compiler for LESS, Sass and CoffeeScript files

Web Essentials 2015.3   3.0.235
Adds many useful features to Visual Studio for web developers. Requires Visual Studio 2015

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC project.
2. Create an ASP.NET Core web project somewhere else.
3. Include the ASP Core project into the ASP.NET project.
4. Use alt+click to drag a css file from the Core project into the content directory of the ASP.NET project.
5. Open a view. Type into a class attribute in a tag, autocomplete works as expected.
6. Close the solution. Open it back up again. Type into a view. Intellisense no longer works. I do get completion for classes already used in the html file though. Just not from the css file.
7. In this case i was not able to solve the issue with a refresh.

Files used:
These are built from sass files in the CORE project using grunt. The lib folder is from bower.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ap_k2H5YNZORgvFqhXkwA9iJXcHAjg

Comment: Hi skinny_pete, the code completion works as expected after reopen VS in my VS 2015 enterprise with update 3. Could you share one of your css/js/image file and upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/, then provide the detail steps to reproduce your issue, I will try to reproduce your issue again in my local.

Comment: I added additional details.

Comment: Hi skinny_pete, could you create a normal css file in the Core project and share into another MVC project, then check if the same issue will happens or not.

Comment: Sara, i tried this and i am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Since this issue is more related to the VS itself, you can try to repair the VS(go to control panel--programs and features and right click the VS 2015 item, select change-repair) and run VS with safe mode using the command: devenv /safemode to check this issue again.